# ImageView dissapearing when inside Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: java, android

In my `ProfileFragment.java` I have a Collapsing Toolbar. When I collapse the toolbar, this problem happens (it's easier to show it in image):

**Please, ignore those objects in the right upper corner**

[image: example problem]

The profile image gets cut. It's the `android:id="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"` that disappears.

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparabackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="203dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFotoCapa"
            android:layout_width="446dp"
            android:layout_height="203dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="-32dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner_profile"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picFotoPerfil3"
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparabackground"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/black" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the attribute `android:elevation="50dp"` to your imageview

Comment: Can't believe that just one line like that solved the problem ahah. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :). Don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Sure, I need to wait 5 minutes so I can green check!

Answer (score 0):

use `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier` used in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:src="@drawable/random_pattern"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

When scrolling we see the following - appbar image starts hiding under the content and beyond the top edge of the screen. Parameter `layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier` determines what part of the image (in percent) will be hidden under the bottom content.

So, for example, setting this parameter to value `1.0` means that top boundary of appbar's image is bound to the top edge of the screen and doesn't move when scrolling. And main content is moving up the top of the image.

When the parameter is not set this corresponds to the value `0.5` and image will be overlapped above and below synchronously.